# what's wrong with my code not able to parse json feed from TMDB site

Tags: java, android, json

**Here is my adapter class**

```
//adapter class

public class AdapterBoxOffice extends      
RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterBoxOffice.ViewHolderBoxOffice> {

private ArrayList<Movies> listMovies=new ArrayList<>();

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

private VolleySingleton volleySingleton;

private ImageLoader imageLoader;

public AdapterBoxOffice(Context context){

    layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

    volleySingleton=VolleySingleton.getInstance();

    imageLoader=volleySingleton.getImageLoader();


}

public void setMovieList(ArrayList<Movies> listMovies){

    this.listMovies=listMovies;

    notifyItemRangeChanged(0,listMovies.size());
}

@Override
public ViewHolderBoxOffice onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int    
viewType) {

   View view= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_movie_box, parent, 
 false);

    ViewHolderBoxOffice viewHolder=new ViewHolderBoxOffice(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderBoxOffice holder, int 
position) {

    Movies currentMovies=listMovies.get(position);

    holder.movieTitle.setText(currentMovies.getTitle());   
    holder.movieReleaseDate.setText(currentMovies.getReleaseDate().toString());

    holder.movieAudienceScore.setRating(currentMovies.getAudienceScore()  
/ 2.0f);

    String urlPoster=currentMovies.getUrlPOster();
    if (urlPoster!=null){

        imageLoader.get(urlPoster, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response,
boolean isImmediate) {


holder.movieThumbnail.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());

            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listMovies.size();
}

static class ViewHolderBoxOffice extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private ImageView movieThumbnail;

    private TextView movieTitle;

    private TextView movieReleaseDate;

    private RatingBar movieAudienceScore;

public ViewHolderBoxOffice(View itemView){

    super(itemView);

    movieThumbnail= (ImageView) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieThumbnail);

    movieTitle= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieTitle);

    movieReleaseDate= (TextView) 
 itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieReleaseDate);

    movieAudienceScore= (RatingBar) 
 itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieAudienceScore);


 }

}

}
```

**Here is my Fragment class**

```
//fragment class

public class FragmentBoxOffice extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private ArrayList<Movies> listMovies=new ArrayList<>();
private AdapterBoxOffice adapterBoxOffice;
private DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
private RecyclerView listMovieHits;


/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentBoxOffice.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static FragmentBoxOffice newInstance(String param1, String param2) 
{
    FragmentBoxOffice fragment = new FragmentBoxOffice();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public static String getRequestUrl() {
    return URL_BOX_OFFICE
            + URL_CHAR_QUESTION
            + URL_PARA_API_KEY + MyApplication.API_KEY;
}

public FragmentBoxOffice() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

    volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
    requestQueue = volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();

    sendJsonRequest();

  }

public void sendJsonRequest() {


    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            getRequestUrl(),
            null + "  ",
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                  listMovies= parseJSONResponse(response);

                    adapterBoxOffice.setMovieList(listMovies);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(request);
  }

private ArrayList<Movies> parseJSONResponse(JSONObject response) {

    ArrayList<Movies> listMovies=new ArrayList<>();

    if (response !=null && response.length() >0) {


        try {


            JSONArray arrayMovies = response.getJSONArray(KEY_RESULTS);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayMovies.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject currentMovies = arrayMovies.getJSONObject(i);

                //get the id of the movies

                long id = currentMovies.getLong(KEY_ID);

                //get the title of the movies

                String title = currentMovies.getString(KEY_TITLE);

                //get the release date of the movies

                String releaseDate = null;

                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_RELEASE_DATE)) {

                    releaseDate = 
 currentMovies.getString(KEY_RELEASE_DATE);
                } else {

                    releaseDate = "NA";


                }

                //get the ratings of the movies

                int audienceScore = -1;

                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_RATINGS)) {

                    audienceScore = currentMovies.getInt(KEY_RATINGS);
                }

                //get the overview of movies

                String overview = currentMovies.getString(KEY_OVERVIEW);

                //get the posters of movies

                String urlPOster = null;

                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_POSTER)) {

                    urlPOster = currentMovies.getString(URL_POSTER + 
 KEY_POSTER);
                }

                Movies movie = new Movies();

                movie.setId(id);

                movie.setTitle(title);

                Date date = dateFormat.parse(releaseDate);

                movie.setReleaseDate(date);

                movie.setAudienceScore(audienceScore);

                movie.setUrlPOster(urlPOster);

                movie.setOverview(overview);


                listMovies.add(movie);

            }




        } catch (JSONException e) {


        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }
    }
        return listMovies;
    }




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_box_office, container,  
false);
    listMovieHits= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieHits);
    listMovieHits.setLayoutManager(new 
LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    adapterBoxOffice=new AdapterBoxOffice(getActivity());
    listMovieHits.setAdapter(adapterBoxOffice);
    sendJsonRequest();
    return view;
}


}
```

**Getter and setter methods**

```
//getter and setter methods


public class Movies {
private long id;

private String title;

private Date releaseDate;

private int audienceScore;

private String urlPOster;

private String overview;


public Movies(){

    this.id=id;

    this.title=title;

    this.releaseDate=releaseDate;

    this.audienceScore=audienceScore;

    this.urlPOster=urlPOster;

    this.overview=overview;

}

public long getId(){return id;}

public void setId(long id){this.id=id;}

public String getTitle(){return title;}

public void setTitle(String title){this.title=title;}

public Date getReleaseDate(){return releaseDate;}

public void setReleaseDate(Date releaseDate)
{this.releaseDate=releaseDate;}

public int getAudienceScore(){return audienceScore;}

public void setAudienceScore(int audienceScore)
{this.audienceScore=audienceScore;}

public String getUrlPOster(){return urlPOster;}

public void setUrlPOster(String urlPOster){this.urlPOster=urlPOster;}

public String getOverview(){return overview;}

public void setOverview(String overview){this.overview=overview;}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ID:"+id+
            "Title"+title+
            "Date "+releaseDate+
            "Vote "+audienceScore+
            "Poster "+urlPOster+
            "Overview "+overview;


}
}
```

Comment: What is the expected and observed behaviors?

Comment: expected to load the data from tmdb api but recyclerview is showing nothing when i am running my app